# Apache Pig 0.10 with CDH3u0 Hadoop failed to work as normal user

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have used Pig, but new to Hadoop/Pig installation.

I have DH3u0 Hadoop installed running Pig 0.8
I downloaded Pig 0.10 and installed it in a separate directory.
I am able to start pig as root user, but failed to start pig as normal user with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Permission denie
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1704)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1792)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:146)
```

Any pointer to the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Also the log file is defaulted to the pig installed directory, is there a way to default the log directory to the user home directory without using the -l option.